# Is there a way on dompdf to manage A4 pages in A3 sheet?

Tags: php, dompdf

I have to generate an A3 with custom parts on every side of A4, how can I proceed with DOMPDF? maybe by inserting margins? or DIVs?

Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify your needs a bit more? It sounds like what you want is to render an A4 document inside an A3 document, with content around the A4 page between it's border and the A3 page border. Is that correct? If so a bit more information on the nature of the additional content would help. You can certainly define page margins such that the content of the document is rendered at A4-size within an A3 page. I'm just not sure about the additional content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. it was enough to create a structure made of DIV.

Thanks anyway